# What are the packages that are related to the empathy IM client?

Tags: empathy, instant-messaging

As far as I know, Empathy has 2 related packages
empathy
telepathy-gabble

I want to know this so that I can update all these packages at one time to update empathy. Hope that gets rid of a few bugs like connection trouble with google talk and empathy window resize bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a study of the dependencies/reverse dependencies of `empathy`, the following packages are "related" (in some way) to empathy:

```
empathy
empathy-common
telepathy-gnome
empathy-call
nautilus-sendto-empathy
indicator-status-provider-mc5
libtelepathy-farstream2
telepathy-gabble
telepathy-haze
telepathy-idle
telepathy-indicator
telepathy-mission-control-5
telepathy-salut
```

You should only upgrade the ones you have installed, don't install any new ones! :)